# Error: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java

Soy principiante en *Java* y tengo una duda en el tema de registros. Estoy realizando un programa de gestión de artículos que permita, entre otras cosas, dar de alta un artículo. El número máximo de artículos que puede haber es `100`. Nos preguntan el código del artículo y si ya existe un artículo con ese código, no se podrá dar de alta. A continuación escribo lo que he realizado gracias a la ayuda de este foro:

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    final int MAXARTICULOS = 100; // {número de artículos máximos de la ferretería}

    class Articulo implements Serializable {

        String codart; // {código del articulo}
        String nombre; // {nombre del artículo}
        String caracteristicas; // {características}
        double precio; // {precio del artículo}
        int cantidad; // {cantidad de artículos en stock}
    }

    Articulo[] misArticulos = new Articulo[MAXARTICULOS]; // {array que contiene los artículos}
    Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
    int menu;

    System.out.println("FERRETERIA");

    for (int i = 0; i < misArticulos.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("Introduce el código: ");
        String codigo = entrada.nextLine();
        boolean encontrado = false;
        for (int j = 0; !encontrado && j < i - 1; j++) {
            if (misArticulos[j].codart.equals(codigo)) {
                System.out.println("Articulo existente");
                encontrado = true;
            }
        }

        if (!encontrado) {
            System.out.println("Introduce el nombre: ");
            misArticulos[i].nombre = entrada.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Introduce las características: ");
            misArticulos[i].caracteristicas = entrada.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Introduce el precio: ");
            misArticulos[i].precio = entrada.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Introduce la cantidad: ");
            misArticulos[i].cantidad = entrada.nextInt();
            entrada.nextLine();
        }
    }

} // fin main
```

Una vez detectado que el artículo no existe, se debe introducir el nombre, las características, el precio y la cantidad pero al ejecutarlo solo me deja introducir el nombre y luego salta la excepción java.lang.NullPointerException.

Comment: Sugerencia... `System.out.println("1-Dar de alta un artículo"); System.out.println("2-Dar de baja un artículo");` se puede cambiar por `System.out.println("1-Dar de alta un artículo" + "2-Dar de baja un artículo");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema por el que te salta una excepción `NullPointerException` es debido a que estas recorriendo en la búsqueda hasta el final de un `array` que aun no has rellenado del todo. Deberías llevar una variable `int` en la que lleves la cuenta de los elementos que llevas y realizar la búsqueda desde 0 hasta esa variable.

Por otro lado si te fijas en los bucles for anidados estás iterando sobre la misma variable i, re iniciándola a cero una y otra vez. Esto va a hacer que en la segunda iteración del bucle principal no entre porque la i ya vale misArticulos.length(). Para ello debes usar otra segunda variable j del siguiente modo:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < misArticulos.length(); i++){
        System.out.println("Introduce el código: ");
        String codigo = entrada.nextLine();
        boolean encontrado = false;
        //buscas hasta que lo encuentras o hasta que llegas al numero de elementos actual
        for (int j = 0; !encontrado && j < i - 1; j++){
            if (misArticulos[j].codart.equals(codigo)){
                System.out.println("Articulo existent");
                encontrado = true;
            }
        }
        if (!encontrado)
            //pides los datos y los metes en misArticulos[i]
    }
```

Existen estructuras de datos como `HashMap` que tiene métodos para comprobar si ya existe un dato dado sin necesidad de recorrer toda la estructura pero si eres principiante en java te recomiendo usar un `array`. Si te interesa puedes saber más en este enlace:
http://jarroba.com/map-en-java-con-ejemplos/

Answer (score 0):

La idea es que primero recorras el array, y mires si existe, antes de hacer nada más, tal que así:

```
boolean encontrado = false;
System.out.println("Introduce el código: ");
String code = entrada.nextLine();
for (int i = 0; i < misArticulos.length; i++) {
   if ((misArticulos[i].codart).equalsIgnoreCase(code)) {
     System.out.println("El código ya existe");
     encontrado = true;
  }
}

if (!encontrado) {
  //Dar de alta
}
```

Si el booleano `encontrado` está a false, es que no existe, por lo tanto ahí tendrias que dar de alta.

PD: Si la propiedad `codart` de tu objeto `Articulo` es un `Integer`, u otra cosa que no sea `String`, deberías de hacer un parse, ya que el método `equalsIgnoreCase` solo es válido para comparar cadenas.